# Diferença entre CSS3 e CSS4

Tags: css, css3

CSS 4 existe? O que tem de diferente do CSS 3? Os navegadores ja suportam?
Estava procurando sobre CSS 3 no Google e vi algumas pessoas mencionarem o CSS 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**FONTE**](http://www.drcode.com.br/css/css4-vem-ai/)

Pois é o css4, mas na verdade o correto não é CSS4 e sim Seletores de Level 4, pois o css 3 como o html 3 foram divididos em módulos, e assim tendo novas mudanças e claro como sempre cada novidade vem sempre para favorecer a nos programadores. Vamos lá vamos entender um pouco sobre css4 e suas principais mudanças em relação ao anterior.

$div .classe
Uma das novas e mais potentes mudanças que houve no css, foi a possibilidade de alterar estilo de uma tag pegando como referencia seus filhos, veja abaixo e entenda melhor

$div a.home {...}
aqui estamos selecionando todas as div’s que tiverem dentro um elemento  com a classe home, e não o a.home

Nos podemos também misturar com vários outros elementos e chamadas, sem a necessidade de encher seu código de id’s ou class.

$div > span {...}
Aqui estaremos estilizando todas as divs que tiverem um filho span diretamente;

$div > span:only-child {...}
Aqui todas que tiverem dentro apenas um elemento span.

:not()
O :not() já esta presente no css 3 mas é importante mostrar sua funcionalidade que agora pode receber mais de um seletor.

*:not(h1, strong) {...}
aqui selecionamos o estilo para todos os elementos, exceto h1, e strong.

input:not(:checked) {...}
Damos o estilo para todos os input, com exceção dos checked

:matches()
Este sem dúvidas vai facilitar muito o nosso trabalho, ele nada mais faz que seleciona e da estilo para todos os seletores dentro de um, sendo assim não mais precisando fazer um monte de linhas de código.

div:matches(span, small) {...}
Olha só que incrivel, ele seleciona todos os span, e small que estiverem dentro da div, genial não ? e ainda pode melhorar olhe só.

:matches(section, div.imagem) img {...}
Aqui selecionamos todas as img que estiverem dentro da section e da div com classe imagem

input:matches(:focus, :hover) {...}
Aqui selecionamos os inputs, com seus estados de :focus que é quando estamos dentro do input e :hover que é ao passar o mouse sobre ele.

Mais em:

[Seletores CSS Nível 4](https://tableless.com.br/seletores-css-nivel-4-o-que-vem-por-ai/)

[Use as facilidades do CSS 4 hoje](https://tableless.com.br/use-as-facilidades-do-css-4-hoje/)

[Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/)

[A novidade deste CSS4](https://blog.groupe-sii.com/les-nouveautes-de-css-level-4/)

Comment: html 3 ? htmml 5 ?

Comment: @zentrunix qual a duvida?  https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/Contents.html

Comment: achei estranho esse "html 3"...

Comment: o artigo não é de minha autoria, só coloquei na resposta pq pode algum dia não estar mais publicado e a fonte não funcionar mais.

Comment: @zentrux antes do HTML5 já teve outras versões mais antigas (HTML4, HTML3...)